# DAX - Get current row number

Tags: dax, row-number

The question seems to be easy but I found it really hard to be done in DAX.
I'd like to get the current row number on my current context data. Same as ROW_NUMBER() in T-SQL.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function. Closest you can get is to calculate rank based on sort-order, like:

```
DEFINE MEASURE SomeTbl[ROW_NO] = SUMX(SomeTbl, RANKX(ALL(SomeTbl), SomeTbl[SortCol]))
EVALUATE ADDCOLUMNS(SomeTbl, "ROW_NO", SomeTbl[ROW_NO])
```

Or if you can't use `RANKX`

```
EVALUATE ADDCOLUMNS (
  SomeTbl, "ROW_NO", COUNTROWS(FILTER(SomeTbl, 
    EARLIER(SomeTbl[SortCol])<=SomeTbl[SortCol]))+0
)
```

Note: for same values (of `SomeTbl[SortCol]`) the `ROW_NO` will be the same.

If you're using DirectQuery mode you can also in model add extra column and define it like`SELECT *, ... ROW_NUMBER() as Foo` - and use `Foo` column in DAX instead.

Comment: Thanks Ondrej, appreciate your answer!